# what cases in which ABP can automatically localize the enums if we follow enum localization conventions

Tags: enums, localization, abp

i try to localized enum property  in DTO  ABP Localization Documentation Say

> We prefer some conventions for specific text types;
> Add Menu: prefix for menu items.
> Use Enum:: naming convention to localize the enum members. When you do it like that, ABP can automatically localize the enums in some proper cases.

[ABP Documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-2?UI=NG&DB=EF#localization)

but i follow this convention and value not localized return enum value

my question : is there automatic way to localize enum or what cases that ABP automatically localize the enums

Comment: You can check abp-select tag helpers here: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Tag-Helpers/Form-elements#label-localization-1

Answer (score 1):

**CarType.cs:** *(enum)*

```cs
public enum CarType
{
    Sedan,
    Hatchback,
    Coupe
}
```

---

**en.json:** *(localization file)*

```json
{
  "culture": "en",
  "texts": {
    "Enum:CarType:0": "Sedan Car",
    "Enum:CarType:1": "Hatchback Car",
    "Enum:CarType:2": "Coupe Car"
  }
}
```

---

**index.js:** *(javascript usage)*

```js
var l = abp.localization.getResource("MyProject");
var localizationKey = "Enum:CarType:" + changeType;
var localized = l(localizationKey);
```

---

**index.cshtml:** *(Razor page usage)*

```
 var statuses = (from CarType ct in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ArticleContentSource))
                select new {Id = (int)ct, Name=L[$"Enum:ContentSource:{(int)ct }"].Value })
                .ToList();
```

---

When [ABP Tag Helpers](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Tag-Helpers/Form-elements) used in MVC projects it's automatically localized via convention like "`Enum:EnumName:Value": "localized text"`

**CarCreateModel.cs:** *(Model)*

```cs
 public class CarCreateModel
 {
     [Required]
     [InputInfoText("Choose car type?")]
     public CarType MyCarType { get; set; }
 }
```

**index.cshtml:** *(MVC page)*

```html
 <abp-select asp-for="@Model.CarCreateModel.MyCarType"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the actual code and I believe the documentation is, at least in part, incorrect.

Here is the framework's code:

```
$"Enum:{enumType.Name}.{memberName}",
$"{enumType.Name}.{memberName}",
memberName
```

So, I think the correct json file format is this:

```
{
  "culture": "en",
  "texts": {
    "Enum:CarType.Sedan": "Sedan Car",
    "Enum:CarType.Hatchback": "Hatchback Car",
    "Enum:CarType.Coupe": "Coupe Car"
  }
}
```